Firestore .data() returns undefined
im making an app with react and nodejs as the server. and im using firebase auth and firestore.
i have a problem, when i create the user is all fine, the user its created well and the user uid and data its stored in the database.
but when i need to get the user data says that its undefined..
async function getUserData(uid) {
    const docRef = doc(db, `users/${uid}`);
    const docCifrada = await getDoc(docRef);
    console.log(docCifrada);
    const data = docCifrada.data();
    console.log(` data: ${data}`);
    return data;
  }

This is the console output, as u can see the docCifrada output its fine but after doing the .data() says undefined:

User data  its not displaying.
Here is the user:

This is how i create users. I use Firebase-admin SDK because I only want the admins to be able to create new users:
async function createUser(email, password, name, rol) {
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:5000/api/user', {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        name: name,
        rol: rol,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/user/info').then((info) => {
      const docRef = doc(db, `users/${info.data.uid}`);
      setDoc(docRef, { email: email, name: name, rol: rol });
    });
  }

server side
app.post('/api/user', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body;
  getAuth()
    .createUser({
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
      displayName: user.name,
    })
    .then((UserRecord) => {
      console.log(UserRecord);
      app.get('/api/user/info', (req, res) => {
        res.send(UserRecord);
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});


So it's .data() that returns undefined? Your title says .doc()

What debugging have you done? Where does uid come from and have you verified that the document exists? You could even check docCifrada.exists() though I suspect the result will be false

yes i have discovered that the uid that is stored in de db is different that the one the user has. i've added how i create the users.

You appear to be registering the app.get('/api/user/info' route every time you request /api/user. That's not going to work how you want it to

I found a fix, i changed the way i store the users in the db, before i stored the user in the front end, now i move the hole thing to the server.

    app.post('/api/user', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
      const user = req.body;
      console.log(user);
      await getAuth()
        .createUser({
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password,
          displayName: user.name,
        })
        .then((UserRecord) => {
          db.collection('users').doc(UserRecord.uid).set({
            email: user.email,
            name: user.name,
            rol: user.rol,
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });


